# Grub-install dummy failed

Tags: installation, grub2, windows-8

While it is installing (any version of Ubuntu) it pops up with a message saying:

```
grub-install dummy failed. This is a fatal error.
```

I have Windows 8 already installed on my computer which is a HP Envy dv7. I have not installed Ubuntu yet, because I can't. Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The error has been seen when the /EFI/ubuntu directory is corrupted (bug 1090829). See comment #25 to fix (get rid of) the corrupted directory -- repeated runs of

```
sudo dosfsck -r /dev/sda2
```

(use your EFI partition if not sda2)
Then the installer may run successfully.

Comment: so install it onto sda2? (or my EFI partition?)

Comment: okay sweet that worked! thanks! now i just need to figure out how to select it, because now it jsut goes straight to windows 8